# How to remove backslash from the end of the string value of a column in a tab separated text file?

Tags: text, awk, sed, grep

I have a tab separated text file with some columns. for some rows the value (which is a string) of a specific column has a backslash at the end of it, which causes problem while I want to import those data to a PostgreSQL database. I want to remove that backslash from the end of the string value of that column for all rows who have it. How can I do this?

for example in this row as you see there is a backslash at the end of second column

```
    862B25B3    Making Large-Scale Nystr{\  making large scale nystr    2010    2010        international conference on machine learning    icml    465F7C62    19555
```

Comment: Test data would be nice.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @JamesBrown it ignores the tabs when i want to paste an example

Comment: Wrap it in block quote or code tags

Comment: Just leave the example there, we can edit your post and cut it.

Comment: Now I added an example correctly @JamesBrown

Comment: Is the trailing `\ ` in question always in the end of second column?

Comment: @JamesBrown Actually I dont know! it's a 30 GB text file I cant just look at it. but I think it will cause problem if backslash would be at the end of any column, so if the answer remove all backslashes at the end of the value of any column it would be good

Comment: In that case it could be in the end of the last column also.

Comment: @JamesBrown is it important if backslash exist at the end of last column? but since it's a integer column, I dont think that it may happen, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk. Use `sub` to replace trailing `\` with `""` (nothing) in the end of the second (`$2`) tab-delimited (`-F'\t'`) column:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'sub(/\\$/,"",$2)||1' foo
```

If the `\` could be in the end of any field, you need to `for' loop it:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/\\$/,"",$i)}1' foo
```

Comment: it seems this command has effect on the tabs. after running this for the file, the backslash has been removed but the tabs between columns also have been removed!

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. I didn't set the `OFS` to tabs as well.

Answer (score 3):

With sed, to remove backslashes before a tab or at the end of line:

```
sed 's/\\\t/\t/g;s/\\$//' file
```